# Update a value when matched in array

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, for-loop

I'd like to change a value when the hostname is `c.example.com`

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "hostname": "a.example.com",
    "Id": "1"
  },
  {
    "hostname": "b.example.com",
    "Id": "2"
  },
  {
    "hostname": "c.example.com",
    "Id": "1"
  },
  {
    "hostname": "d.example.com",
    "Id": "1"
  }
]
```

I can match the item

```
data=[{"hostname":"a.example.com","Id":"1"},{"hostname":"b.example.com","Id":"2"},{"hostname":"c.example.com","Id":"1"},{"hostname":"d.example.com","Id":"1"}]
for item in data:
    if item['hostname'] == 'c.example.com':
          # how to update its id to 10 and write it back to data
```

How to update its id to 10 and write it back to data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
sample_data = [
{
"hostname": "a.example.com",
"Id": "1"
},
{
"hostname": "b.example.com",
"Id": "2"
},
{
"hostname": "c.example.com",
"Id": "1"
 },
{
"hostname": "d.example.com",
"Id": "1"
}
]

for item in sample_data:
    if item['hostname'] == "c.example.com":
        item['Id'] = 10

print(sample_data)
```

Explanation:

Using `for-loop` iterate over the elements and using `if` search for `c.example.com`. If it matches using `=` operator assign a new value to `Id`

Output:

```
[{'hostname': 'a.example.com', 'Id': '1'}, {'hostname': 'b.example.com', 'Id': '2'}, {'hostname': 'c.example.com', 'Id': 10}, {'hostname': 'd.example.com', 'Id': '1'}]
```

Comment: @Bill: It is tested and got like your required output. Is this what you are expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

Direct assignment should work fine here:

```
for item in data:
    if item['hostname'] == 'c.example.com':
        item['Id'] = '10'
```

Comment: Thanks, I think with too complex way.

Answer (score 1):

With `item['Id'] = 10` ?

```
for item in data:
    if item['hostname'] == 'c.example.com':
        item['Id'] = 10
```