# how to update whole part after matched

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

A further question about [Update a value when matched in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458339/update-a-value-when-matched-in-array)

```
data=[{"hostname":"a.example.com","Id":"1"},{"hostname":"b.example.com","Id":"2"},{"hostname":"c.example.com","Id":"1"},{"hostname":"d.example.com","Id":"1"}]

update={"hostname":"c.example.com","Id":"10"}

for item in data:
    if item['hostname'] == 'c.example.com':
       item = update

print(data)
```

Why the output isn't updated

```
[{'hostname': 'a.example.com', 'Id': '1'}, {'hostname': 'b.example.com', 'Id': '2'}, {'hostname': 'c.example.com', 'Id': '1'}, {'hostname': 'd.example.com', 'Id': '1'}]
```

Why `item['Id'] = 10` works, but `item = update` doesn't work?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment (`=`) doesn't change a variable in place.

Here are 2 options to solve this:

1. change the list instead of the item in the list:

`for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i]['hostname'] == 'c.example.com':
       data[i] = update`

2. update the dict itself. (`update` is an in-place method)

`for item in data:
    if item['hostname'] == 'c.example.com':
       item.update(update)`

This works only if the keys in your `update` variable overlap with the keys in the item.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the element in data and append `update`:

```
data=[{"hostname":"a.example.com","Id":"1"},{"hostname":"b.example.com","Id":"2"},{"hostname":"c.example.com","Id":"1"},{"hostname":"d.example.com","Id":"1"}]

update={"hostname":"c.example.com","Id":"10"}

for item in data:
    if item['hostname'] == 'c.example.com':
        data.remove(item) # remove the condition satisfied element
        data.append(update) # append the update

print(data)
```

Explanation:

The `=` operator here doesn't update your `data` element. So you can make use of `remove` and `append` to delete old one and add new one.

When you use `item = update` it means you are making the `item` refers to `{"hostname":"c.example.com","Id":"10"}` but not updating the actual `data`

Output:

```
[{'hostname': 'a.example.com', 'Id': '1'}, {'hostname': 'b.example.com', 'Id': '2'}, {'hostname': 'd.example.com', 'Id': '1'}, {'hostname': 'c.example.com', 'Id': '10'}]
```

Comment: @Bill: You got clarified ?

Comment: why `item['Id'] = 10` works and update in `data` directly?

Comment: @Bill: when you are doing `item['Id'] = 10` you are updating the value of a dictionary item by specifying using the respective key. So it is getting updated in `data`.

Comment: @Bill: I updated my explanation. Let me know you need clarification ?

Answer (score 1):

### `x = something`

If you have something assigned to x, e.g. `x = object1`, then if you write `x = object2`, that does not influence `object1`* (or any other data, for that matter) in any way. It just means that variable `x` now refers to a different object (`object2` rather than `object1`).

### `x.y = something`

On the other hand `x.y = something` does influence data (in general case). It modifies data in `x`. It still does not modify data which was previously in `x.y`* - that old data is just no longer referenced by `x.y`.

### `x['y'] = something`

This has very similar semantics as `x.y = something`.

### The original example

```
for item in data:
    if item['hostname'] == 'c.example.com':
       item = update
```

After `item = update`, variable `item` no longer references an item from `data`, it references a different variable: `update`. If you `print(item)` you will see that.

The line that is execute after that is `for item in data`, which again changes what `item` references, thus effectively cancelling the previous line.

What you actually want is to modify `data`, so you should do so, e.g.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    ...
    data[i] = update
```

---

(*) Although the original data is not modified by this, it may be "deleted" i.e. it's memory may be freed if it is no longer referenced by any variable, because it is no longer needed.